# Proof of parametrisation of $\hat{\mathfrak{g}}$-intertwiners of induced modules of affine Lie algebras

Tags: rt.representation-theory, lie-algebras

I am not *100%* sure that this question belongs here, since I think the topic does but the specific problem I have might not. Feel free to tell me so if this is the case. It concerns the proof of Theorem 3.1.1. in the book "Lectures on Representation Theory and Knizhnik-Zamolodchikov Equations by" Etingof, Frenkel and Kirillov, Jr. A small part of it can be viewed here: https://books.google.nl/books?id=wNrxBwAAQBAJ&printsec=frontcover&hl=nl#v=onepage&q&f=false.

Let $\mathfrak{g}$ be a simple Lie algebra over $\mathbb{C}$, let $\mathfrak{h}$ be a Cartan subalgebra, let $L(\hat{\mathfrak{g}})=\mathfrak{g}\otimes\mathbb{C}[t,t^{-1}]$ be the loop algebra, let $\hat{\mathfrak{g}}=\mathfrak{g}\oplus\mathbb{C}\{c\}$ be the unique nontrivial central extension of $L(\mathfrak{g})$, and let $\tilde{\mathfrak{g}}=\hat{\mathfrak{g}}\oplus\mathbb{C}\{D\}$ be the affine Lie algebra, where $D$ is the derivation of $\hat{\mathfrak{g}}$ that acts as $\mathrm{id}_{\mathfrak{g}}\otimes t\frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}t}$ on $L(\mathfrak{g})$ and as zero on $\mathbb{C}\{c\}$. Let $\tilde{\mathfrak{g}}^+=\mathfrak{g}\otimes\mathbb{C}[t]\oplus\mathbb{C}\{c\}\oplus\mathbb{C}\{D\}$.

Let $\lambda\in\mathfrak{h}^\ast$, let $k,\Delta_\lambda\in\mathbb{C}$, and let $L_\lambda$ be the irreducible quotient of the Verma module $M_\lambda$ of $\mathfrak{g}$. Denote by $V_{\lambda,k}$ the induced module $\mathrm{Ind}^{\tilde{\mathfrak{g}}}_{\tilde{\mathfrak{g}}^+}L_\lambda=\mathcal{U}(\tilde{\mathfrak{g}})\otimes_{\mathcal{U}(\tilde{\mathfrak{g}}^+)}L_\lambda$, where $L_\lambda$ has been turned into a $\tilde{\mathfrak{g}}^+$-module by letting $\mathfrak{g}\otimes t\mathbb{C}[t]$ act as zero and $c$ and $D$ by constants $k$ and $-\Delta_\lambda$. We are assuming that $\lambda$ is generic with respect to $k$, meaning that $V_{\lambda,k}$ is an irreducible $\tilde{\mathfrak{g}}$-module. There is a gradation induced by $D$, i.e.
$$
V_{\lambda,k}=\bigoplus^\infty_{n=0}V_{\lambda,k}[n]
$$
where $V_{\lambda,k}[n]$ is the eigenspace of $D$ with eigenvalue $-n-\Delta$. The degree 0 component is isomorphic $L_\lambda$.

The theorem is now the statement that for any $\mathfrak{g}$-intertwiner $g:L_\lambda\to L_\mu\otimes V$, with $\mu\in\mathfrak{h}^\ast$ and $V$ a weight module of $\mathfrak{g}$ (so it has a weight decomposition with respect to $\mathfrak{h}$, with finite-dimensional weight spaces), there exists a unique $\hat{\mathfrak{g}}$-intertwiner $\Phi^g(z):V_{\lambda,k}\to V_{\mu,k}\hat{\otimes}V(z)$ such that on the 0th level this map is just $g$. Here $z$ is a nonzero complex number and the hat denotes the completed tensor product with respect to the gradation induced by $D$, and $V(z)$ is the $\mathfrak{g}$-module where $c$ acts as zero and $(x\otimes t^n)v=z^nxv$.

Two conditions characterise this intertwiner uniquely, the first one being the fact that $\Phi^g(z)w\in(V_{\lambda,k}\hat{\otimes}V(z))^{\mathfrak{g}\otimes t\mathbb{C}[t]}$ and the second that it equals $g$ on the 0th level.

The argument proceeds as follows: First of all, $\Phi^g(z)w\in(V_{\lambda,k}\hat{\otimes}V(z))^{\mathfrak{g}\otimes t\mathbb{C}[t]}=\mathrm{Hom}_{\mathfrak{g}\otimes t\mathbb{C}[t]}(V^\ast_{\lambda,k},V(z))$. Here $V^\ast_{\lambda,k}$ is the restricted dual but **not with the action of $\hat{\mathfrak{g}}$ twisted by a Chevalley involuton**, so $V^\ast_{\lambda,k}=\bigoplus_\Lambda V_{\lambda,k}[\Lambda]^\ast$, where $\Lambda$ ranges over the weights of $V_{\lambda,k}$.  Furthermore, the fact that $V^\ast_{\lambda,k}$ is freely generated over $L^\ast_\lambda=(V_{\lambda,k}[0])^\ast$ implies that the restriction map $\mathrm{Hom}_{\mathfrak{g}\otimes t\mathbb{C}[t]}(V^\ast_{\lambda,k},V(z))\to\mathrm{Hom}_{\mathbb{C}}(L^\ast_\lambda,V)$ is an isomorphism (of what? $\mathfrak{g}$-modules? I hope so.). Finally, we have that $\mathrm{Hom}_{\mathbb{C}}(L^\ast_\lambda,V)=L_\lambda\otimes V$.

My problem lies with actually all of these equalities/isomorphisms, and a couple of other things.

- To start with, why is $\mathrm{Hom}_{\mathbb{C}}(L^\ast_\lambda,V)=L_\lambda\otimes V$? There is some infinite-dimensional stuff swept under the rug here it feels like, and my tries at breaking both modules up in their weight spaces has so far been unsuccessful.
- Same thing for $(V_{\lambda,k}\hat{\otimes}V(z))^{\mathfrak{g}\otimes t\mathbb{C}[t]}=\mathrm{Hom}_{\mathfrak{g}\otimes t\mathbb{C}[t]}(V^\ast_{\lambda,k},V(z))$, which I would say should be an iso instead of an equality anyways.
- Why is $V^\ast_{\lambda,k}$ freely generated over $\mathfrak{g}\otimes t\mathbb{C}[t]$ by $L^\ast_\lambda=V_{\lambda,k}[0]^\ast$? Why are the weight spaces of $V_{\lambda,k}$ finite-dimensional?

Thanks so much for any help. I have gotten stuck in these details while I want to move on to KZ equations and the bigger story here :)

*Extra thoughts*

Intuitively, I thought that the iso $L_\lambda\otimes V\to(V_{\lambda,k}\hat{\otimes}V(z))^{\mathfrak{g}\otimes t\mathbb{C}[t]}$ should be just the inclusion, but this can't be it since $x\otimes t^n$ acts as zero on $L_\lambda$ but not on $V$., in general.